# GMX contact form

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, contact-form

I'm trying to create a simple SMTP-contact form with the help of phpMailer for my homepage but it's not working. It should forward the information of the fields "name, mail, subject, message" to my mailbox (in this case "name, mail, subject, message"). The input fields are also named "name, mail, subject, message" in my html code.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks for any advice.

```
<?
  require('class.phpmailer.php');    
  require('class.smtp.php');

    $mail = new PHPMailer(); 
            $mail->CharSet  =  "utf-8";
            $mail->IsSMTP();
            $mail->Host       = 'mail.gmx.de';
            $mail->SMTPDebug  = 0;                     
            $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;           
            $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                 
            $mail->Port       = 465;                     
            $mail->Mailer   = "ssl"; 
            $mail->Password = "****"; 
            $mail->Username = "test@gmx.com"; 
            $mail->SMTPAuth  =  "true"; 

            $mail->FromName = $_POST['name']; 

            $mail->AddAddress = $_POST['mail'];  

            $mail->Subject = $_POST['subject'];  

            $mail->Body = $_POST['message']; 

            if(!$mail->Send())   
            {  
            echo 'E-Mail not send.';  
            echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;  
            }   
            else   
            {  
            echo "<h5>" . 'Thanks for your message' . "</h5>";  
            }  
?>
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: "error:You must provide at least one recipient email address."

But I thought it is this part of the code, isn't it? 

$mail->Username = "test@gmx.com";

Comment: *"but it's not working"* - how is it not working? You did not state what the problem is/was.

Comment: You've based your code on an outdated example, so you're probably using an old version of PHPMailer too. [Get the latest](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says you are missing the recipient address, you have to add one using:

```
$mail->AddAddress("youemail@youremail.com", "Your Name");
//Your Name is optional. so alternatively you could do:
//$mail->AddAddress("youemail@youremail.com");
```

The part of the code you reference `$mail->Username = "test@gmx.com";` simply sets the username for authenticating with the SMTP server, not the recipient address.

Comment: Thank you so much! It's working properly now :-) But I have one more problem. My contact form is not being reset when I hit the submit button. Do you have a clue how I can solve this problem?

Here's the link to my contact form:
http://k-urz.de/v8

Comment: Add `document.getElementById("contactform").reset();` to the method you use when submitting the form.

Comment: This works fine for resetting the contactform. Thanks :)

But now I get the error "Message body empty" although I put text in this field. What's going wrong?

Comment: You are probably resetting the form before you send it.

Comment: I'm using the js function in the html part of my submit button:    `<input class="submit three columns" type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" onclick="resetform()"/>` How can I delay the trigger of that function?

Comment: You would put the `document.getElementById("contactform").reset();` at the end of your submit method `$('#submit').click(function(){ //code goes here });`

Comment: Thank you so much! I fixed the problem with the help of a TimeOut. For those who are interested:
   `<div class="row">
    <input class="submit three columns" type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" OnClick="setTimeout('resetform()', 200); return true"/>
   </div>`